# Strategy choosing problems using Bayes theorem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Q no: 1
You are selling a product in an area where 30 % of the people live in the city and the rest live in the suburbs. Currently 20 % of the city dwellers use your product and 10 % of the suburbanites use your product. You are presented with two new sales strategies the first will increase your market share in the suburbs to 15 %. The second will increase your market share in the city to 25 %. Which strategy should you adopt? What percentage of the people who own your product are city dwellers before your new sales drive?

Q2:
In a casino in Blackpool there are two slot machines: one that pays out 10 % of the time, and one that pays out 20 % of the time. Obviously, you would like to play on the machine that pays out 20 % of the time but you do not know which of the two machines is the more generous. You thus adopt the following strategy: you assume initially that the two machines are equally likely to be the generous machine. You then select one of the two machines at random and put a coin into it. Given that you loose that first bet estimate the probability that the machine you selected is the more generous of the two machines?

I need solutions of these two questions by using Bayer's Theorem .

Comment: Have you tried applying the Bayes formula?

Comment: Yes but I cannot understand the logic that how I implement Bayer's Theorem on it that's why I need a solution.

Answer (score 1):

P(you will win in I) $= .1$

P(You will win in II) $= 0.2$

P(you will lose in I) $= 0.9$

P(you will lose in II) $= 0.8$

P(I is generous) $= x$

P(II is generous) $ = x$

P(you lose in I/ I is generous) $= \frac{1}{2}.(0.9)x =.45x$

P(you lose in II/ II is generous) $= \frac{1}{2}.(0.8)x = 0.4x$

P(II is more generous/ you lose) $= \frac{0.40}{0.4+0.45} = \frac{0.40}{0.85}$

Part 1 does not require Bayes theorem. You want to see in total percentage of the population which strategy brings in more users.

1) 25% market share increase of $1.25(20$%$ (30$%$)) = 7.5$%

2) 15% market share increase of $1.15(10$%$(70$%$)) = 8.05$%

Given the price is the same in both the city and suburb, I would choose a strategy that will bring more of the general population to use your product which is Suburbs strategy I.

(20%(30%)) = 6% are city dwellers that use your product

(10%(70%)) =  7% are suburbanites that use your product

Fraction of people who use your product are city dwellers $= \frac{6}{6+7}  =\frac{6}{13}$